# Conditional expectation of uniform random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

I am trying to find $E[Y|X+Y=c]$ where $X$ is a uniform random variable on $[-1,1]$ and $Y$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$ and $X,Y$ are independent.

I know that for discrete events, we have Bayes' Rule of $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A \cap B)$. As far I am aware, this also applies to densities. Density of $X+Y=c$ is $4/9 + 4c/9$ for $c \leq 0.5$ is my guess. However, I struggle to evaluate the numerator.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: Consider _definition_ of conditioning on a single value of a continuous RV. Technically, $P(X+Y=c) = 0,$ so the denominator would be 0. How does one deal with that?

Comment: Do we have something similar to Bayes' Rule for density functions? I.e. we simply plug in the densities into Bayes' Rule. That is at least what I have tried to do so when I said the density of $X+Y$ is ...